# Findig a solution for a linear equation system which has more variable then equtions

Tags: algorithm, math, gaussian, solver, linear-equation

Let's divide the problem to 2 parts, the second one is optional.

Part 1

I have 3 linear equtions with N variables where N usually bigger then 3.

- x1*a+x2*b+x3*c+x4*d[....]xN*p = B1
- y1*a+y2*b+y3*c+y4*d[....]yN*p = B2
- z1*a+z2*b+z3*c+z4*d[....]zN*p = B3

Looking for (a,b,c,d,[...],p), others are constant.

The standard Gaussian way won't work because the matrix will be wider then tall. Of course i can use it to eliminate 2 variables. Do you know an algorithm to find out a solution? (I only need one.) More 0s in the solution coefficients are better but not required.

Part 2

The coefficients in the solution must be non-negative.

Requirements:
The algorithm must be fast enough to run real time. (1800 per sec on an avrage pc). So trial and error method is a no go.
The algorithm will be implemented in C# but feel free to use pseudo language if you want to write code.

Comment: This sounds like homework.  What have you tried, where are you stuck?  The answer to Part 1 is just basic linear algebra; find yourself any basic textbook and it'll explain the case where the matrix is wider than tall.

Comment: Then point me please to the right direction with some links or keywords. It's not a homework, i can assure you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com is the ideal forum for the first question.

Comment: I thought using constraint programming to find the coefficients. Limit range to 0-1 in R fits for me. I found a C# solver (Mono so Microsoft solver foundation doesn't plays), that may works but i'm afraid not enough fast for me. Do anyone know a good constraint solver for c#?

Comment: An other way to solve this is SVD. I will write to solution when i tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Set extra variables to zero. Now we have the matrix equation

A.x = b, where

```
   x1 x2 x3
```

A =    y1 y2 y3
       z1 z2 z3

b = (B1, B2, B3), as a column vector
Now invert A. The solution is;

X = A<sup>-1</sup>.x

End matrix formula's in excel with Ctrl Shift Enter

Comment: Singular matrix doesn't have an inverse.